# Unable to get ASP.Net controller to process JSON posted data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, parameter-passing, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am using asp.net 4.5 and have the following controller.

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // POST: /Account/JsonLogin

    [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Login(LogIndto loginRequest)
    {
        if ( loginRequest.Email == null )
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        return null;
    }
}
```

here is my dto

```
    public class LogIndto
{
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public Boolean RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

based on fiddler this is what is being posted to my service

```
POST host/Account/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 71
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: clientDifferentThanHost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer:clientdifferentThanHost/?
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"Email":"keith@kssoftware.net","Password":"afasdf","RememberMe":false}
```

I expect ASP.Net to convert the JSON to the C# Object but instead all data in loginRequest is null (except the boolean which has the default value of false)

here is the javascript that I am using

```
    this.Login = function () {
    var dto = JSON.stringify({Email:"test@test.com",Password:"avafa",RememberMe:false});
    $.ajax({
        url: app.homeUrl + "Account/Login",
        data: dto,
        success: self.loginSuccess,
        processData: false,
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
        }).fail(self.loginFail)
    ;
};
```

When I try to set the contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"  the request never makes it to the service.  I assume this is an bug in the Thinktecture.IdenityModel cross-origin package I'm using but will try to figure that out once I can get this to work.  any help will be appreciated.  I have gotten this to work in the past and I'm sure I just need a second set of eyes to help.

using fiddler I've been able to pass the following as well

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8900/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"loginRequest":[{"Email":"test@test.com","Password":"avafa","RememberMe":false}]}
```

still no values are processed correctly

Answer (score 0):

looks like the issue was that the contentType has to be = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"  I moved the service to be from the same origin and changed the contentType and it worked as expected.

Will investigate why contentType change is causing issues with Thinktecture

Comment: Looks like it was pretty easy to config Thinktecture to accept different contentType. http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/